# How to add export button in catalog page Magento 2.1.8

Tags: magento-2.1

I need to add export functionality in catalog page(which contains all the products).Im using magento 2.1.8 in my project.

Answer (score -1):

**You can use this snippet in Grid xml: Hope this will help you**

```
<exportButton name="export_button">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">os_adjuststock_listing.os_adjuststock_listing.adjuststock_template_columns.ids</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </exportButton>
```

Comment: Can u tell me the file location(Grid xml)

Comment: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

Comment: This doesn't work.